# What can hostile mobs attack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know they attack villagers but I think those are the only type of mob they will attack? Can they attack anything else that I should protect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mobs that attack each other:

- Golems (iron and snow) > all hostile mobs
- all hostile mobs > you, anything that attacks them (skeleton shoots a zombie by accident zombie attacks skeleton)
- Cats > Chicken
- Wolves > Sheep
- Zombies > Villagers
- Iron Golems > any player that attacks them or nearby villagers, skeletons, zombies, and witches
- Tamed wolf > anything player attacks or is attacked by

In answer to your question, your livestock should be safe from anything but wild wolves and cats (except for splash damage from witches or creepers, or stray skeleton shots).

Comment: Should be noted if a hostile NPC has a target already, not all of them will switch targets that easily. A zombie coming after you will continue to come at you even if a skeleton shoots it.. Some for Creepers really. Spiders I am a bit more unsure of.. and Skeletons change immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Foxes also will attack chickens in the new update.